# LeakCanary detected webview memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, webview, leakcanary

I use `LeakCanary` in the android application, the problem is as follows:
[Check this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoNeY.png)

find a solution，replace：

**onCreate:**

```
LinearLayout webViewHolderLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.webview_linearLayout);
newsView = new WebView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
webViewHolderLayout.addView(newsView);
```

**onDestroy:**

```
newsView.removeAllViews();
newsView.destroy();
```

Problems still exist...

Help！！！

Answer (score 0):

seems like webview bug, fixed in Marshmallow https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/92